# Prevent dragging to move the empty cell in css grid

Tags: javascript, css-grid, sortablejs

I would like to make a cell to not move in  `sortablejs`.

All items are draggable and sortable except for `.clearing`. However, you can move any other divs around or in front of `.clearing` and force it to move. Try to move A or B to the beginning of the grid (left top corner) and observe `.clearing` is pushed down the grid.

[image]

I would like to disable that and ensure `.clearing` can not be moved at all. Thanks

```
    .wrapper {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
      grid-gap: 10px;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #444;
    }
```

https://codepen.io/zocoi/pen/xxbogZw

EDIT: updated screenshot, description and codepen with current undesired behaviour

Comment: Like this? https://codepen.io/Chris-Happy/pen/MWYMjBo

Comment: can you share a kind of screenshot? not clear what you mean by *clearing*

Comment: thanks @Paulie_D, I updated the description and codepen to reflect the actual question, hopefully it will be clearer now

Comment: @ChrisHappy sorry I wasn't clear before, would you mind having a look again?

Comment: @Paulie_D We have a design where `clearing` is actually an upload button and the rest are images. You can reorder images but the upload/dropzone are always the first element in the grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select which elements are draggable.

```
$(()=>{
  const wrapper = $("#wrapper")[0]
  Sortable.create(wrapper, {
    draggable: '.box'
  })
})
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Chris-Happy/pen/ZEYdLaE?editors=1010)

Alternatively, you can use `draggable: 'div:not(.clearing)'` or something similar.

Comment: or just use `filter` option

Answer (score 2):

Since sortable.js actually re-orders the HTML all we need to do is determine the location of the "clearing" div and the natural grid flow will take care of the rest.

Remove the "clearing" filter from the sortable.js code and *lock* the required div into its required place in the grid with:

```
grid-row:1;
grid-column:1
```

```js
$(()=>{
  const wrapper = $("#wrapper")[0]
  Sortable.create(wrapper)
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 120px 120px 120px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  cursor: grab;
}

.clearing {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
  grid-row:1;
  grid-column:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.10.1/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
  <div class="clearing" title="but I can be moved by moving others around me">Can't move me</div>
  <!-- should not allow dragging any element before this .clearing, try to drag A before here and it does move -->
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```